# Laravel cannot add foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Something broke in my migrations file as I am doing a `migrate:fresh` and it throws:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint 
(SQL: create table `product` (`test` int not null) default character 
set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

I have deleted everything in that migration and left only one field in order to debug what may be the issue, and here is the migration as is now and the one which is giving me this error:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('test');
    });
}
```

I tried doing `composer dump-autoload` but nothing changed.

**EDIT**

After doing `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` the first error I'm getting after `migrate:fresh`is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; 
duplicate key in table '#sql-4ef_4' (SQL: alter table 
`product_shipping_country` add constraint `fk_psc_product` foreign key 
(`product_id`) references `product` (`content_id`) on delete CASCADE on 
update CASCADE)
```

But immediately after I run `migrate:fresh` this error is no longer present, and I am getting the old one again

**EDIT 2**

I tried manually deleting the DB, same thing happens. Also clearing both `composer clear-cache` and `artisan cache:clear`

**EDIT 3**

If I delete that migration, and every migration after that one, the error is gone, so I suppose the error is in that specific migration?

I don't get how can I get `foreign-key` error when I even don't have foreign keys in the migration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some cache issue obviously. I resolved it by completely deleting the DB and creating it again. Migrations and reseeds worked perfectly after that.